How to prevent the "_ready" events and pre-ready var declarations in a loaded, instantiated scene?
I have a simple save game/load game system that packs the entire world scene to the disk, then loads it via ResourceLoader.load():
var loadedGame = ResourceLoader.load(SAVEGAME_PATH,"",ResourceLoader.CACHE_MODE_IGNORE).instantiate()

It works fine, and the game state is somewhat successfully saved/restored. The problem is that upon loading the game (i.e. instantiating the loaded scene) all _ready events on ALL the nodes inside it are fired off again and all variables that were declared pre-ready are re-declared (i.e. revert to the original values).
Is there a way to suppress these _ready events and re-declarations in this specific use case?


Is there a way to suppress these _ready events and re-declarations in this specific use case?

By strictly answering your question "as asked", you could suppress the Node.NOTIFICATION_READY issued by the SceneTree by defining your own MainLoop and implementing dedicated logic to handle the "brand-new Scenes vs. file-loaded Scenes" scenario.

However, this is overkill for a simple save/load system. Rather than suppressing NOTIFICATION_READY notifications, you can instead execute _ready() callbacks selectively by using a boolean flag and a guard clause:
extends Node

@export is_initialised: bool = false
# Other variables here

func _ready() -> void:
    if is_initialised: return
    # Initialisation logic here
    # ...
    is_initialised = true

You must @export all attributes relevant to the game save, and never set their value in _ready(): @exported attributes persist when both saving/loading from a file and using Node.duplicate(). You only need to set their default value during declaration or in the Inspector, and they will keep their last assigned value during the whole game execution. If you have something like:
@export var current_hp: int = 100

and then you set current_hp to 80 from the Inspector, the latter value will be used instead of the former (Inspector overrides declaration). On the other hand, if you have:
@export var current_hp: int = 100

func _ready() -> void:
    current_hp = 50

and then you set current_hp to 80 from the Inspector, then current_hp will always equal 50 regardless of everything else. Don't use _ready() for data that depends on files, instead use it for regular attributes only once the @exported and @onready are initialised.

This here is the simplest, correctest answer to the otherwise complex problem! I wasn't aware that @export-s persist, it makes a ton of sense now. Huge kudos, thanks!

It would be possible to override the Object._notification() method on a per Node basis (since that method is virtual) however none of the methods in SceneTree are virtual, so I don't see any way to suppress the NOTIFICATION_READY using your own custom SceneTree implementation. I am assuming you wouldn't directly subclass MainLoop since you would now have to re-implement all the engine logic for managing scenes in GDScript.


Is there a way to suppress these _ready events and re-declarations in
this specific use case?

I don't think so, but since Godot is open source, you could probably hack the engine (C code) to do that.
A really horrific kludge would be to move all your @on_ready initializations into the _ready() method then add a guard condition to the _ready() methods - specifically you could check a boolean property on an autoload object and bail if the property is set.

Note: both of my previous suggestions are really trying to answer your question "as asked".
However I don't think I would use either of those approaches, instead I would start by reviewing the Godot save game tutorial: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/io/saving_games.html
And then use a combination of explicit persistence (tagged objects) on the scene tree and directly saving a separate data model for more complex state.

From the OP's comment:

I am actually baffled as to why _ready and the pre_ready variables
cannot be suppressed in native godot. Given that the Res.packer,'s
purpose is to preserve the scene state "as is", it seems
self-defeating to immediately ruin the packed scene's carefully
preserved state by re-initializing everything.

My understanding is that there are three systems involved here:

The GDScript language initialization.
Packed Scenes / @export system.
The "ready" system.

(1) When any object is created it is first initialized using the GDScript init system:

Any variable that is not marked with @onready is initialized.
If defined the _init() function is called.

(2) Next, if an object is being created from a packed scene it's @export variables are set, based on the values stored in the packed scene.
(3) Finally the subtree (created from the packed scene) is attached to the scene root, this triggers the "ready" system:

@onready vars are initialized.
The _ready() function is called.

I am guessing that the reason why the "ready" system can't be suppressed, is because it is not necessary to do so - specifically code in the "ready" system should only be used to initialize any variables that are dependent upon being attached to to the scene root (basically node lookups) and/or transient state (state that is derived from other persisted values).

Thanks for the really verbose response! I am actually baffled as to why _ready and the pre_ready variables cannot be suppressed in native godot. Given that the Res.packer,'s purpose is to preserve the scene state "as is", it seems self-defeating to immediately ruin the packed scene's carefully preserved state by re-initializing everything. I'll check the savegame tute again, though as far as I'm concerned it really overcomplicates saving given that 3 lines of code using Res.packer can potentially achieve the same if it wasnt for _ready and var re-inits...
